# Given $\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}∈GL_2^+(R)$ , $\beta(w)=\frac{aw+b}{cw+d},\Im(w)>0$.Is $\beta$ bijective?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given any matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}∈GL_2^+(R)$, we can define a function $\beta:H\to{ \mathbb{C} }$ by $$\beta(w)=\frac{aw+b}{cw+d},w∈H$$,where $H$ is the upper complex plane.Is $\beta$ bijective?

I compute the imaginary of $\beta(w)$,$$\Im(\beta(w))=\frac{|A|}{(cw+d)^2}\Im(w)$$
then $\beta(w)∈H$.So $\beta:H\to{H}$. And I think it is a bijection,but I fail to prove that it is an onto. Could you show that $\beta$ is a bijection or not?Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to compute the inverse of $\beta$. In other word, we solve for $w$ in term of $\beta$, namely, $z=\frac{d\beta-b}{-c\beta +a}$

So for for each $k \in \mathbb{C}$ ,$\exists$ $z=\frac{dk-b}{-ck +a}$, such that $\beta(z)=k$ which gives the surjectivity of $\beta$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to find an inverse function.

$\beta(\omega)=\frac{a\omega+b}{c\omega+d}\Rightarrow \omega(c\cdot\beta(\omega)-a)=b-d\beta(\omega)$ or $\omega=\frac{b-d\beta(\omega)}{c\beta(\omega)-a}$.  Therefore we have $\beta^{-1}$ given by $\begin{pmatrix}-d&b\\c&-a\end{pmatrix}$.  Since $\beta$ has an inverse, $\beta$ is bijective (Note: $\frac{d-b\beta(\omega)}{c\beta(\omega)-a}=\frac{b\beta(\omega)-d}{a-c\beta(\omega)}$ so, more intuitively, the matrix inverse $\begin{pmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{pmatrix}$ is an inverse).